# irobot_create_2_1 installation not working

Tags: ros, installation, irobot-create-2-1

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to install irobot_create_2_1 package but the installation failed during the make step. I followed the steps as given in the following link
([www.ros.org/wiki/irobot_create_2_1](http://www.ros.org/wiki/irobot_create_2_1))

When i run "rosmake irobot_create_2_1 ", the following is the output I get.

```
   user@ubuntu:~/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1$ rosmake irobot_create_2_1 
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                                                          
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['irobot_create_2_1']                                                                
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/user/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130416-140004                                  
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['irobot_create_2_1'] to:
['irobot_create_2_1']                                                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> catkin [ make ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< catkin ROS_NOBUILD in package catkin                                  [ 1 Active 0/35 Complete ]
 No Makefile in package catkin                             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genmsg [ make ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                                                             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package genmsg
 No Makefile in package genmsg                             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genlisp [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genlisp ROS_NOBUILD in package genlisp
 No Makefile in package genlisp                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> genpy [ make ]                                                                                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< genpy ROS_NOBUILD in package genpy
 No Makefile in package genpy                                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> gencpp [ make ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< gencpp ROS_NOBUILD in package gencpp
 No Makefile in package gencpp                             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_generation [ make ]                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_generation ROS_NOBUILD in package message_generation
 No Makefile in package message_generation
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospack ROS_NOBUILD in package rospack
 No Makefile in package rospack                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
 No Makefile in package cpp_common                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
 No Makefile in package rostime                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                                                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
 No Makefile in package roscpp_traits        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
 No Makefile in package roslib                             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
 No Makefile in package rosunit                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                                                             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
 No Makefile in package rosconsole                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                                                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
 No Makefile in package roscpp_serialization
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> message_runtime [ make ]                                                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< message_runtime ROS_NOBUILD in package message_runtime
 No Makefile in package message_runtime  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang                          
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
 No Makefile in package xmlrpcpp                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
 No Makefile in package std_msgs                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                                                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
 No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
 No Makefile in package rosgraph                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
 No Makefile in package geometry_msgs        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
 No Makefile in package roscpp                             
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                                                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
 No Makefile in package rospy                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam
 No Makefile in package rosparam                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                                                              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster
 No Makefile in package rosmaster                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout
 No Makefile in package rosout                             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                                                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
 No Makefile in package sensor_msgs              
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                                                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles
 No Makefile in package angles                             
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean
 No Makefile in package rosclean                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]                                                                              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
 No Makefile in package roslaunch                    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                                                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest
 No Makefile in package rostest                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]                                                                               
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nav_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package nav_msgs
 No Makefile in package nav_msgs                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                                                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters
 No Makefile in package message_filters  
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                                                                     
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf
 No Makefile in package tf                                         
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> irobot_create_2_1 [ make ]                                                                      
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesobot_create_2_1: 39.4 sec ]                                          [ 1 Active 34/35 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
  
  
  -- Build files have been written to: /home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build
  cd build && make -j -l2
  make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build'
  make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build'
  [  0%] Built target rosbuild_premsgsrvgen
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build'
  [  8%] Built target ROSBUILD_genmsg_py
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build'
  [ 50%] Built target ROSBUILD_gensrv_cpp
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build'
  [ 95%] Built target ROSBUILD_gensrv_py
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build'
  [100%] Generating ../msg_gen/cpp/include/irobot_create_2_1/SensorPacket.h
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/genmsg_cpp.py", line 44, in <module>
      msg_gen.generate_messages(sys.argv)
    File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/msg_gen.py", line 740, in generate_messages
      generate(arg)
    File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/msg_gen.py", line 710, in generate
      write_traits(s, spec, cpp_prefix, rospack=rospack)
    File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/msg_gen.py", line 588, in write_traits
      gendeps_dict = roslib.gentools.get_dependencies(spec, spec.package, compute_files=False, rospack=rospack)
  TypeError: get_dependencies() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rospack'
  make[3]: *** [../msg_gen/cpp/include/irobot_create_2_1/SensorPacket.h] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ROSBUILD_genmsg_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package irobot_create_2_1 written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/user/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130416-140004/irobot_create_2_1/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< irobot_create_2_1 [FAIL] [ 39.52 seconds ]                                                      
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package irobot_create_2_1. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.     
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                     
[ rosmake ] Built 35 packages with 1 failures.                                                                           
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                  
[ rosmake ] /home/user/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130416-140004                                                       
user@ubuntu:~/groovy_workspace/brown_drivers/irobot_create_2_1$
```

The make process is failing. Any help??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60781/irobot_create_2_1-installation-not-working/) by [Dayanand](https://answers.ros.org/users/4686/dayanand/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Works for me. [This question](http://answers.ros.org/question/59929/rosmake-uwsim-error-1-package-failed/) has a similar error message:

```
get_dependencies() got an unexpected keyword argument 'rospack'
```

One answer mentioned that updating roslib solved it, so maybe you could try that.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dayanand](https://answers.ros.org/users/4686/dayanand/) on 2013-04-17**:
Thank you Martin. Updating roslib has solved the problem.